# Problem with calculation of dot product of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have such a question from the exercises given by the professor

> $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are two vectors on the plane and $\vec{w}=\vec{u}+\vec{v}$. We suppose that $||\vec{u}|| = 3$ and  $||\vec{v}|| = 5$ and $\vec{w} \vec{u} = 0$. Please calculate $\vec{u} \vec{v}$

According to the answer key, the procedure is as following

- $\vec{u} \vec{v}$ = $\vec{u}(\vec{w}-\vec{u})$
- =$\vec{u}\vec{w}-\vec{u}\vec{u}$
- =$0-||\vec{u}||^2$
- =-9

However, from my understand, the formula of dot product should be $\vec{u} \vec{v} = ||\vec{u}||||\vec{v}||cos\theta$

So why the $cos\theta$ is not calculated here?

Comment: Do you know how to compute dot products using the coordinates of the vectors?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the coordinates are not given.

Comment: The dot product of vectors with coordinates is easy as $u_1v_1+u_2v_2$. However, that would require me actually knowing the coordinates of each vector no?

Comment: You don't immediately know the angle between $u$ and $v$, so you can't use that formula to find the dot product. But now that you have the dot product, you could find that angle if you wanted.

Comment: @Ned I am sorry, but I did not understand what you mean? I am not trying to find the angle. The answer provided did not calculate the angle (While the dot product of geometric vector requires the calculation of angle). So I am not sure why, in this question, they did not calculate and get the answer for the dot product

Comment: @Ned. Because as far as I am concerned, either you know the coordinates and then use $u_1v_1+u_2v_2$ without the need of the angle,  or you use $\vec{u}\vec{v}=||\vec{u}||||\vec{v}||cos\theta$ where the angle is needed

Comment: But those two methods are not the only way to compute a dot product. In this problem you don't have co-ordinates and you don't know the angle, so another method, because of the particular given information in the problem, can be used to find that the dot product equals -9. The point is, your two formulas may be the most common methods to compute dot products, but they are not the only ones!

Comment: Seems like the statement of problem says $vw=0$ but the solution given assumes $uw=0$. That's probably why the answer below is different.

Answer (score 1):

You are given $\vec w \cdot \vec u =0$.

Note $\vec w \cdot \vec u = (\vec u +  \vec v) \cdot \vec u$

$= \vec u \cdot \vec u +   \vec v  \cdot \vec u $

(distributivity of the dot product)

$=\vec u \cdot \vec u +   \vec u  \cdot \vec v $

(commutativity of the dot product)

$= | \vec u|^2+\vec u \cdot \vec v$

So, $| \vec u|^2+\vec u \cdot \vec v=0$

$3^2+\vec u \cdot \vec v =0$

$\therefore \vec u \cdot \vec v = -9$

Comment: That is to say, the answer to this question is wrong? Because there are actually three others sub-question to this in which all of them involve the result from this first question, and all of them uses -9

Comment: It would appear your answer key is wrong as long as you presented the question exactly right. Check.

Comment: Okay. I will write to the professor to verify! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you should. But first ensure your question is written correctly here as I said. Because your question stipulates wv=0, but your answer key assumes uw=0.

Comment: Or the answer key swapped the norms of the two vectors.

Comment: @deepak. Thank you. It is my fault, the font for the exercise on my paper was very confusing for me. It should be wu = 0. I almost send the email to my professor

Comment: @YanZhuang No worries. I was driving to work when I accepted your edit. But I have further improved the presentation and explicitly stated the axioms I am using. If this answer has been helpful, please accept it. Thank you.